# Databinding to a property in code behind but with a different datacontext

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Is there a way to databind to a property in the codebehind of a wpf control, while having a different datacontext??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for every binding you can set the [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.source.aspx) explicitly. You can use StaticResource or RelativeSource to get where you want.

```
 <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding MyDataContext}" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyOtherDataContext} Path=PropertyFromOtherDataContext}" />
```

Comment: and how do I set myotherdatacontext to point to the code behind of that wpf control?

Comment: <Label Margin="3,3,3,3" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CLASSNAME}}}" Content="{Binding PROPERTyNAME}" />